# Is it possible to mock or patch a input parameter in perl?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mocking

It seems that in python, mock.patch can patch an input

Is it possible to mock a input parameter in perl? and how? Here is the output:

```
not ok 1 - expect: 59, got: 1
```

The code I had so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Test::More;
use Test::MockObject;
use Date::Calc;

# scope of mocked Date::Calc
{
    my $import;
    my $mock = Test::MockObject->new();
    $mock->fake_module('Date::Calc', import => sub { $import = caller} );
    $mock->fake_new('Date::Calc');
    $mock->mock('Days_in_Year', sub {print "how to mock parameter - month to be 2\n"});
    # is it possible to mock a parameter? how if possible?
    my $days_mock = $mock->Days_in_Year(2015,6);
    ok($days_mock == 59, "expect: 59, got: $days_mock\n");
}

# unmocked module and methods
my $days_in_year = Date::Calc::Days_in_Year(2015,6);
ok($days_in_year == 181, "expect: 181, got: $days_in_year\n");
done_testing(2);
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more detailed what you are trying to do, and why?

Comment: @simbabque, I am new to mock as most of my unittests cannot proceed without mock. It seems to me that mocking a parameter is similar to mocking a variable inside a sub, but mocking a parameter now seems to be unnecessary after your asking why. I have no idea how to do it in perl. thanks

Comment: You don't mock a variable. You mock a dependency. That can be a sub, or an object, or even a whole RDBMS. You should read up on dependency injection. Show your program and explain which part you want to write the test for, and I will help.

Comment: @simbabque, I think your comments is the answer that I am looking for, I had the wrong concept about mocking, If you copy the comment to the answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot mock a variable, you have to mock a dependency. That dependency can be a sub, an object, or maybe even a whole RDBMS. The code in the question looks like it's a test to prove that the mocking works, so I will try to stick with that in my examples.

When you mock an object, that is called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). I will talk about that later on in the answer.

For reasons of space and [laziness](http://threevirtues.com/), please assume every single piece of code in this answer starts with:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
```

### Mocking a single sub

Sometimes that's not possible because of the way the code is designed. In that case, you need to mock a function (which is a sub in Perl) or two, or maybe a whole module. The latter is hardly ever needed.

The easiest way to override a single sub (or several) is [Sub::Override](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Override). It's useful for unit testing, but not limited to it.

```
use Test::More;
use Sub::Override;
use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->now;

{   # scoped in this block
    my $override = Sub::Override->new( 'DateTime::year', sub { 2015 } );
    is $dt->year, 2015, 'Year is 2015';
}

isnt $dt->year, 2015, 'Year is NOT 2015';

done_testing;

__END__
ok 1 - Year is 2015
ok 2 - Year is NOT 2015
1..2
```

As we can see, the sub was overridden, but only in the given scope. That is pretty useful, because it is quick, easy to remember and also easy to read, which is a very important factor to consider. Here is a made-up example.

```
package Foo;
require Weird::Legacy::Dependency;

sub hello {
    my $name = shift;
    my $hi = Weird::Legacy::Dependency::rnd_salutation();
    return "$hi, $name";
}
```

In this code that we need to test, there is a horrible legacy dependency that we cannot yet refactor. The author was fond of spagetti, and the stuff is pretty illegible. It might return stuff like this:

```
Hi, Bob
Hallo, Bob
Good Afternoon, Bob
Բարեւ, Bob
```

So how do we deal with that? Of course, we override the sub `rnd_salutation`.

```
use Test::More;
use Sub::Override;

{   # scoped in this block
    my $override = Sub::Override->new(
      'Weird::Legacy::Dependency::rnd_salutation', sub { 'Hi' } );
    is Foo::hello('Joe'), 'Hi, Joe', 'Say hi to Joe';
}
```

Now we can make sure that `hello` does exactly `<given_salutation>, $name`  although we don't know what kind of random stuff is coming out of the legacy function.

### Mocking an object

If your code is object-oriented, you can make every dependency injectable. That way, you can controll even more. A very typical example of that is a database connection, or an LWP object. Here is a simplified example. This code could be a full-blown client for some API.

```
package My::WebserviceClient;
use Moose;
use LWP::UserAgent;

has ua => (
    is      => 'ro',
    isa     => 'LWP::UserAgent',
    default => sub { LWP::UserAgent->new },
);

sub call {
    my ($self, $url) = @_;

    my $res = $self->ua->get($url);
    return $res->content if $res->is_success;
}

package main;

my $client = My::WebserviceClient->new;
print length $client->call('http://www.example.org');
```

Now to test that, we don't want it to actually go and fetch something. So we need to mock it. Let's make a [mock object](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockObject) that has a `get` method and returns a fixed [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response).

```
use Test::More;
use Test::MockObject;
use HTTP::Response;
use My::WebserviceClient;

# prepare the mock object
my $mock = Test::MockObject->new;
$mock->set_isa('LWP::UserAgent');

# set up a response object
my $res = HTTP::Response->new( 200, 'OK', [], 'Hello' );
$mock->set_always( 'get', $res );

# here we INJECT the DEPENDENCY
my $client = My::WebserviceClient->new( ua => $mock );

is $client->call('http://www.example.org/'), 'Hello', 
  'Just the content is returned';

done_testing;

__END__
ok 1 - Just the content is returned
```

This will work, because the `get` method in the mocked user agent now always returns our prepared HTTP::Response object. This way, we can also test whether the program handles 404 repsonses correctly.

### Mocking both at the same time

But sometimes it's not possible to inject the dependency. What if the author of the program was too lazy<sup>1</sup> to set up a property for the user agent and did this instead?

```
package My::WebserviceClient;
use Moose;
use LWP::UserAgent;

sub call {
    my ( $self, $url ) = @_;

    my $res = LWP::UserAgent->new->get($url);
    return $res->content if $res->is_success;
}
```

Now the injection does not work any more. We need to do something else. Test::MockObject discourages the use of its `fake_module` method, because Test::MockModule can do a better job. We need to use it to mock the `new` method in LWP::UserAgent, so it returns our mocked user agent object that we did in the test before.

```
use Test::More;
use Test::MockObject;
use Test::MockModule;
use HTTP::Response;
use My::WebserviceClient;

# prepare the mock object
my $mock_ua = Test::MockObject->new;
$mock_ua->set_isa('LWP::UserAgent');

# set up a response object
my $res = HTTP::Response->new( 200, 'OK', [], 'Hello' );
$mock_ua->set_always( 'get', $res );

# Now we need to mock LWP::UserAgent's new to return our
# mocked object
{
    my $module = Test::MockModule->new('LWP::UserAgent');
    $module->mock( 'new', sub { return $mock_ua } );

    my $client = My::WebserviceClient->new;
    # inside of call, it will now use our mocked LWP::UA::new
    is $client->call('http://www.example.org/'), 'Hello', 
      'Just the content is returned';
}

done_testing;

__END__
ok 1 - Just the content is returned
```

Of course in this case we could have used Sub::Override as well. I think this is a matter of preference.

Also note that there is [Test::LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::LWP::UserAgent), which provides a lot of nice features for the specific case of mocking a user agent. I just picked LWP as a quick example. For real code, I would prefer Test::LWP::UserAgent.

## Mocking other stuff

If you need to deal with a database (like MySQL), it's nice to use [DBD::sqlite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::sqlite) and dependency injection to just supply a fake complete database, but a real [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI). That even works with [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class). On the other hand, if the database code is part of what you want to test, to verify e.g. if the code inserts the right stuff, you can use [Test::DatabaseRow](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::DatabaseRow). In general, it's good to just look at the Test:: namespace on CPAN. There are some fun things on there. You can [mock the `time`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Time), or a [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::URI), or [the output of external scripts](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Cmd), or even [wrap all your tests in individual Moose classes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Class::Moose) to organize your test suite in a nice way.

I suggest taking a look at *Perl Testing: A Developer's Notebook* by Ian Langworth, which gives a pretty broad introduction to the matter. Another good resource is [Ovid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8003/ovid)'s [free test training on github](https://github.com/Ovid/example-test-training-material).

---

<sup><sup>1)</sup> Note that this is the bad kind of lazy!</sup>

Comment: Oops. This thing turned out longer than I intended... I hope it's useful to someone. :)

Comment: Wow, mocking seems fun.. Thanks for the nice introduction.

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes, it's very useful. Unfortunately there are no really good guides for modern testing of more complicated programs available online. It's all very small things, or just documentation. Maybe someone should write one as a blog.perl.org post... Sounds like I'm volunteering... :D

Comment: my goal is to benefit 10 readers for your answer, There are not many perl mocking posts around.

Comment: @g thank you for being so happy about my answer. I'm really flattered. But remember that it's for the community as well. One day you might be the random guy on the Internet that invests half an hour of their time to help a total stranger. It's great having those people, but it's also fun to be that guy once in a while. Learn and participate here. And maybe watch https://youtu.be/CjOQZf0Ad74, you might enjoy it. :-)